# How should I organize my nested form in flutter?

Tags: reactjs, flutter, dart

I'm ReactJS developer and now I would like to write some flutter app for my self, just to try the new technology, some kind of my ideal project.

So I have nested form, like Task with Subtasks and I have parent widget (let's call it TaskView) for render Task's fields and render children task as a separate widgets (let's call it SubtaskView).

So the question is where and how should I store and update state of this form?
Should it be stored some kind like ReactJS way, all in the parent component, be immutable and be updated on every change with rebuild all children widgets (because flutter doesn't have something like ReactJS memo)?
Should it be strongly immutable or opposite it's not recommended?
May be it should be divided, by widgets (Task's data in TaskView and Subtask's data in SubtaskView) but if so when I will press "Save" button in parent widget (TaskView) how could I get data about subtask from child widgets?

Maybe you could recommend me an article or example about how to work with forms and scale them in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal approach in Flutter. It all depends on how complex your widgets are.

If you subtask only has two states, for example "complete" and "incomplete", and the widget itself is fairly simple, then you should render it as a StatelessWidget with a property `complete`. Your TaskView can hold the state of the Task with all of its subtasks, because rebuilding the entire view will be fast and "cheap".

On the other hand, if your subtask is more complex to render, or has some of its own logic, then you may not want to rebuild the entire TaskView every time there is a change to one subtask. Then you make your subtask a stateful widget.

For example, if there is some nice animation as a user marks subtask complete, a subtask widget may rebuild many times to show just one smooth animation. In such case you definitely should avoid rebuilding the entire screen on every tick of the animation controller.